# Anaconda R Kernel Notebook Error - with custom R library path

Tags: r, anaconda

I'm currently using Rstudio and Anaconda and am having trouble starting Anaconda R Kernel. Below is the error prompt received.

My environment variables do point to a path which stores my RStudio libraries. Does repointing default library path causes issues in Anaconda R Kernel?

Appreciate your help.

Thanks,
James

[image]

[image]

```
[I 15:19:18.595 NotebookApp] Kernel started: ddadae8b-dfe7-4392-ad1f-0b4b7157bdad, name: ir
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) :
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/xxx/Downloads/rlibs/rlang/libs/x64/rlang.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found.
Calls: :: ... namespaceImport -> loadNamespace -> library.dynam -> dyn.load -> inDL
Execution halted
[I 15:19:21.598 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), new random ports
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) :
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/xxx/Downloads/rlibs/rlang/libs/x64/rlang.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found.
Calls: :: ... namespaceImport -> loadNamespace -> library.dynam -> dyn.load -> inDL
Execution halted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here

https://richpauloo.github.io/2018-05-16-Installing-the-R-kernel-in-Jupyter-Lab/

Find the location of R.exe on your computer. In my computer this executable is at: C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin

Open another Anaconda Prompt as Adminstrator and change directories to wherever R.exe is on your computer with cd file path. On my computer it’s: cd C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin, but it might be different for you.

Then run R from within Anaconda Prompt in Admin mode with R.exe.

You’ll notice that you’re in an R session. From here, run the following three commands into the terminal.

install.packages("devtools")

devtools::install_github("IRkernel/IRkernel")

IRkernel::installspec()

In order, they (1) install the devtools package which gets you the install_github() function, (2) install the IR Kernel from github, and (3) tell Jupyter where to find the IR Kernel.